# Premature privilege achievement notification

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, notifications, achievements-dialog

A few days ago, I got a notification in my Achievements dropdown that says "You've earned the "talk in chat" privilege! Learn more about it in the help center."

[image: Privilege notification]

I immediately went over to participate in [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46067/tcl) chatroom, but found that I wasn't allowed to do so yet.

The help center shows that this privilege is still 3 reputation away.

[image: Hepl center privilege meter]

Why have I been notified prematurely?

Comment: You may have been receiving that message due to a temporary upvote that was retracted later.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that is not the case because then we're talking about 3 votes that were then retracted... unlikely because not only did I not do anything to warrant such attention in a short span, but I definitely did not do anything that could make 3 people want to retract it just as quickly either.

Comment: One upvote would be 5 or 10 points.

Comment: Alright. That makes it a lot more believable then. But shouldn't the notification of the awarded privilege go away in case of such retraction (it is still in my Achievements notifications)? As far as I (the end user) am concerned, it is misleading. And although not a huge nuisance, it is a bug, and one that could easily be set right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get a notification **as soon as** you hit the reputation requirement. If you subsequently lose a few points and drop below the requirement the notification isn't removed as it's highly likely that you'll regain those points very soon. Unfortunately if you view the site during that window it looks like you've been awarded the privilege early.

If you got it *every* time you reached the rep requirement you could end up getting it three or four times as your rep bounced around the score.

This would be more annoying than temporarily finding that the you didn't have the privilege.

The only other solution would be to delay the notification until you were well over the score or had been over the score for a significant time, but that would lead to people complaining that the notification hadn't arrived or had arrived late. It also wouldn't solve the case of when you drop below a privilege level as a result of issuing a bounty.

Look on it as an incentive to provide more good content.

Comment: I get your point - I can imagine how that could get annoying. However, I feel a simple solution like a strikethrough over such a notification (one that is invalid after it was generated) could solve both issues, and stave off what could possibly be a much bigger misunderstanding than a talk in chat privilege.

Comment: It might not be a bug (as asserted above), but surely it _**is**_ a design flaw. A better design -- one way to correct this flaw -- is to make the act of changing a user's reputation into a transaction. The 1st phase occurs when the up- or down-vote happens, and 2nd ("commit") phase begins when 5 minutes have passed from the original vote without a retraction. This way, reputation and privilege are only affected by votes that can no longer be retracted. They can still waffle, but only if opposite votes are coming in from different people.

Comment: Or just make privileges be like bridge so once you get them, you keep them.

Comment: Or require you have been over the required rep for 24hr to get the privilege.  Eg. check as part of the bridge scripts.