# Achievement notification says I've earned the downvote privilege, but rep is only 121 and I still cannot downvote

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, privileges, achievements-dialog

I received a notification under Achievements yesterday stating:

```
You've earned the "vote down" privilege! Learn more about it in the help center.
```

However, I still cannot downvote questions or answers on SO.

My understanding is that this privilege is earned at 125 rep, but my current rep only shows 121. I have not lost any rep since the notification (my only loss of rep was back in May), so I'm not sure:

- why I received this notification if I have not yet reached 125 rep, or
- how my rep has been reduced since receiving the notification, without being shown under Activity -> Reputation -> post/time in my user page (I have the "show removed posts" option ticked)

Can someone help me understand why I appear to have been erroneously notified that I have earned this privilege?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This happens when somebody upvotes one of your questions/answers (gaining you 5/10 reputation), but decides to retract his/her vote within the 5 minute [vote lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72154/how-long-does-it-take-to-lock-in-a-vote) window. The reputation is retracted as well, and this doesn't show up in your reputation history. The notification for new privileges is sent out almost instantaneously after the upvote, and apparently it can't be retracted.

Comment: And there's no way for me to see my upvotes which were subsequently retracted to confirm that this is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: No, but let me upvote one of your posts and retract it, so that you can see it happening again.

Comment: Interesting - I saw my rep go up to 131 as a result of your upvote (and then back down to 121 after you retracted it), but I did not see the Achievement notification again - do we only get Achievement notifications the first time we cross the rep threshold for that achievement, even if we subsequently lose rep and cross the same threshold again? If so, it would seem more useful to me if we were notified **each time** we gained the necessary rep for a privilege...

Comment: @3N1GM4 well, it could be annoying if you received the same notification multiple times. See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274306/premature-privilege-achievement-notification?rq=1) for a similar case.

Comment: Ok, I can see this from both sides, although personally I agree with [Slaiyer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3645308/slaiyer) in the question you linked to - I personally feel that I would prefer to be notified each time (as something has still changed, my ability to leverage the new privilege) and perhaps old redundant notifications could either be removed from my Achievements Dialog or struck through or similar to indicate they are no longer appropriate. I'll just have to go get some more rep to get back over the threshold! :)

Comment: nice way to troll news comers, I wonder if it's the same for all privileges ?

Comment: Perhaps the acheivement notifications should only be sent out AFTER the vote lock window has passed.

Comment: Well, some people can't wait five minutes before trying out their new toys...

Comment: @AntonChanning That wouldn't entirely eliminate this. You could also lose the privilege due to downvotes (or bounties, though that's less likely to be a surprise).

Comment: Complete elimination might be impossible, but easy to avoid misnotifications should be.

Comment: As for waiting, if they don't know they might have those toys for five minutes, then they won't technically be waiting to try them out. ;)

Comment: @AntonChanning But they could have done it in those seconds between the upvote and the retraction.  Sucks to be them that they lack the reaction time.  :)